# Apache Tomcat 7.0.26 - No access to symlink folders inside Aliased folder

Tags: tomcat

I have a web application deployed in my ROOT of Tomcat. I have made an entry in context.xml of META-INF for aliases as

```
Context aliases="/h1=/opt/apache2/test/sample/h1"
```

I have three directories namely `h11`, `h12` and `h13` in `h1`. Of these directories, `h12` directory has a symbolic link to say `/var/text/hello/scripts`

When i access `/h1/h11/xxx.html` or `/h1/h13/yyy.html` I'm getting the content, whereas when I access `/h1/h12/test.js` I'm not able to access it

Any idea on how to resolve this issue of having symlinks inside aliased folder and accessing the contents in symlink folder??

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the Tomcat docs for the allowLinking attribute for the Context.

Comment: Hi Mark, I went through the docs and tried to implement by what was given there. But it is not working for me. The allowLinking works only when it is given in the server.xml's Context tag. Something like <Context path="/" docbase="/opt/apache2/test/sample" debug="0" reloadable="true" allowLinking="true"/>. for this I need to create a symbolic link h1 in /opt/apache2/test/sample. If I do this, the symbolic link and the contents under them also gets deleted when undeploying the application
If allowLinking is given in the application's Context.xml, it is not recognised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.  Found a few things that refer to context.xml's "allowLinking" parameter (Example: http://www.isocra.com/2008/01/following-symbolic-links-in-tomcat/ ), but I haven't been able to get Tomcat to follow links on Mac OSX 10.6.8 running Tomcat 7.0.21 and 7.0.28.

Comment: Update: I had to do the symbolic linking via the command line ('ln /path/to/dir mydir') as opposed to Mac's Option+Command drag-and-drop.